# Replace ending of words with a new ending in python dataframe

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, text-mining

I have a Dataframe full of french words, endings and new endings. I want to create a 4th column with the alternative to the word as such:

```
word   |ending|new ending|what i want|
--------------------------------------
placer |cer   |ceras     |placeras   |
placer |cer   |cerait    |placerait  |
placer |cer   |ceront    |placeront  |
finir  |ir    |iras      |finiras    |
```

So it's basically to replace, in column 1, what's equivalent in column 2, by what I have in column 3.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
df['new_word'] = df.apply(
    lambda row: row['word'].replace(row['ending'], row['new ending']),
    axis=1
)
#     word ending new ending   new_word
#0  placer    cer      ceras   placeras
#1  placer    cer     cerait  placerait
#2  placer    cer     ceront  placeront
#3   finir     ir       iras    finiras
```

As @jpp pointed out, a caveat to this approach is that it won't work correctly if the ending is present in the middle of the string.

In that case, refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3675318/how-to-replace-the-some-characters-from-the-end-of-a-string) on how to replace at the end of the string.

Comment: @jpp that is an excellent point. I've added a note about that.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way using `.loc` accessor:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'word': ['placer', 'placer', 'placer'],
                   'ending': ['cer', 'cer', 'cer'],
                   'new_ending': ['ceras', 'cerait', 'ceront']})

df['result'] = df['word']
df['lens'] = df['ending'].map(len)

df.loc[pd.Series([i[-j:] for i, j in zip(df['word'], df['lens'])]) == df['ending'], 'result'] = \
pd.Series([i[:-j] for i, j in zip(df['word'], df['lens'])]) + df['new_ending']

df = df[['word', 'ending', 'new_ending', 'result']]

#      word ending new_ending     result
# 0  placer    cer      ceras   placeras
# 1  placer    cer     cerait  placerait
# 2  placer    cer     ceront  placeront
```

Comment: I notice you use -3, but it's entirely possible the length of the ending isn't (I have edited my question to reflect that). So I want the solution to work for everything at once.

Answer (score 2):

here is another solution :

```
df.word.replace(df.ending, '', regex=True).str.cat(df["new ending"].astype(str))
```

and the output :

```
0     placeras
1    placerait
2    placeront
```

Comment: This solution does not only replace endings.

Comment: Be more precise please